# Can't ping a linux server with MacOSX. Software related

Tags: macos, network, time-machine, bootcamp, unix

I'm having an huge problem with my Mac, from months.

I have at home a linux server, a CuBox. It's running Archlinux, running fine. Everything works.

But the Mac can't ping the CuBox.

I will paste you a little log of what a ping gives.

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 669
Request timeout for icmp_seq 670
Request timeout for icmp_seq 671
Request timeout for icmp_seq 672
Request timeout for icmp_seq 673
Request timeout for icmp_seq 674
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 675
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 676
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 677
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 678
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 679
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 680
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 681
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 682
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 683
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 684
```

And this cycling again and again. The issue is Mac software related, on Windows (Boot Camp) I can ping the CuBox.

With the help of reddit, http://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/19vbwf/mac_cant_ping_linux_server/ I made it working for 2h. The next day, (after making the computer sleep) the problem happened again.

For making things works 2h, I have played with sharing settings, disabling and enabling again. This trick is not working anymore now.

I really need to access to this CuBox. If anyone have a clue, please tell me what to test!

Thanks.

Comment: What does your routing tables says ? ( `netstat -r` )

Comment: What does your firewall say?

Comment: What happens when you ping your router's IP address? What happens when you ping the IP of the Linux box instead of its host name?

Comment: netstat -r -> http://paste.placeholder.fr/show/202/ No firewall on both. I ping always ip.

Answer (score 3):

I recently solved a very similar problem by removing my ARP cache.

I have a MacBook Pro 2014 and Ubuntu 18.04 desktop which runs the SSH daemon, and every client works fine except my MacBook.

I ran Wireshark and observed that pinging my desktop is only resulting in ARP requests to be broadcasted — I couldn't see response packets. At first I thought it's a problem with my router interface, but since other computers worked fine that made little sense.

At last I decided I found out that I can remove my laptop's ARP cache by running this:

```
sudo arp -d <desktop's_ip>
```

and it solved my problem!
This solved my problem!

Comment: I wish I could try this out, but obviously it's not a problem anymore... Maybe your answer will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had an Ubuntu Server that I could reach with a Windows machine, but not a MacOS machine.

It turned out, I configured my Linux server to have a static IP address, and didn't add the `renderer: networkd` argument. Curiously, I was able to reach the server through a Windows machine. I was able to find this because I had a Raspberry Pi which was reachable by both my Windows and Mac computers, and I compared the Pi's netplan configurations with my server's.

After adding `renderer: networkd`, the problem instantly went away. This may be a solution specific to my situation, but thought I'd put it out there in case anyone else searches for this problem.

Obviously, this does not explain why the solution works; I am not familiar enough with networkd and network rendering. I invite others to pitch in and provide explanations.